# Find filename that contain hex value?

Tags: bash, grep, ascii

I would like to correct a bad encoding for thousand files. The error is always the same, an unknown char should be replaced with a french `é`.

```
$ find . -type f | grep 127427
./documents/1778_commande_127427_accus�_de_r�ception.pdf

$ find . -type f | grep 127427 | hexdump -C
00000000  2e 2f 64 6f 63 75 6d 65  6e 74 73 2f 31 37 37 38  |./documents/1778|
00000010  5f 63 6f 6d 6d 61 6e 64  65 5f 31 32 37 34 32 37  |_commande_127427|
00000020  5f 61 63 63 75 73 ef bf  bd 5f 64 65 5f 72 ef bf  |_accus..._de_r..|
00000030  bd 63 65 70 74 69 6f 6e  2e 70 64 66 0a           |.ception.pdf.|
0000003d
```

So I am looking for `ef bf bd` which does not look like an unicode char. Unfortunately looking for the `0xef` does not work:

```
$ find . -type f | grep -P '\xef'
(nothing)
```

Any clues?

Next I am planning to do something like:

```
$ find . -type f | grep <magic-here> | xargs -n1 -I{} sh -c 'mv "{}" $(echo "{}" | sed s/<magic-here>/é/) '
```

Comment: `an unknown char should be replaced with a french é` careful, that unknown character is likely to be a placeholder for any character that couldn't be encoded in a previous step, and that would likely include other symbols such as `è`, `à`, `ç` and `œ` (although that wouldn't be a problem if you're only handling acknowledgments of receipt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
echo $'\x2e\x2f\x64\x6f\x63\x75\x6d\x65\x6e\x74\x73\x2f\x31\x37\x37\x38\x5f\x63\x6f\x6d\x6d\x61\x6e\x64\x65\x5f\x31\x32\x37\x34\x32\x37\x5f\x61\x63\x63\x75\x73\xef\xbf\xbd\x5f\x64\x65\x5f\x72\xef\xbf\xbd\x63\x65\x70\x74\x69\x6f\x6e\x2e\x70\x64\x66\x0a'\
| grep -Fa $'\xef\xbf\xbd'
```

`-a` treats binary files as text. `-F` performs a fixed string search, no regular expressions. `$''` is an [ANSI string](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/ANSI_002dC-Quoting.html)

---

The find command should look like this:

```
find ... -exec sed $'s/\xef\xbf\xbd/é/g' {} +
```

When you are sure that it works, use `-i`, this will change files in place:

```
find ... -exec sed -i $'s/\xef\xbf\xbd/é/g' {} +
```

Comment: The idea is not to change files in place, but rename them

Comment: Got it, let me change that

Comment: This gets time consuming, let me finish it this evening